# how to get the index of the largest n values in a multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to get the index of the largest n values in a multi-dimensional numpy array. For get the index of the largest n values in a one-dimensional numpy array, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337533/a-fast-way-to-find-the-largest-n-elements-in-an-numpy-array). After test in interactive shell in python, it seems that `bottleneck.argpartsort` can't effect on multi-dimensional numpy array. For get the index of the largest value in a multi-dimensional numpy array, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584243/python-get-the-position-of-the-biggest-item-in-a-numpy-array). It can't get the largest n. The method that i can give is translate the multi-dimensional numpy array to a list of `{value:index}`(index present by a tuple), and then sort the list by the value, and get the index for it. Is there anything more easier or more performance?

Comment: Reshape to one dimension, then search, then get the original indexes through arithmetic calculations involving the dimensions before the reshape?

Comment: Maybe `flatten()` the original array, then use your 1D solution, finally calculate the real nD indices using the original shape?

Comment: What is the problem with the second link? Can you show us a part of this multi-dimensional array? I don't see why it shouldn't work ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603747/get-the-indices-of-n-highest-values-in-an-ndarray

Comment: @plonser the second link only return the index of the maximum value of the multi-dimensional numpy array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have access to `bottleneck`, so in this example I am using `argsort`, but you should be able to use it in the same way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
N = 4
a = np.random.random(20).reshape(4, 5)
print(a)

# Convert it into a 1D array
a_1d = a.flatten()

# Find the indices in the 1D array
idx_1d = a_1d.argsort()[-N:]

# convert the idx_1d back into indices arrays for each dimension
x_idx, y_idx = np.unravel_index(idx_1d, a.shape)

# Check that we got the largest values.
for x, y, in zip(x_idx, y_idx):
    print(a[x][y])
```

Comment: Use [`argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) instead of `argsort` and you'll earn my upvote. ;-)