# Quickest way to find the nth largest value in a numpy Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

There are lots of solutions to do this for a single array, but what about a matrix, such as:

```
>>> k
array([[ 35,  48,  63],
       [ 60,  77,  96],
       [ 91, 112, 135]])
```

You can use `k.max()`, but of course this only returns the highest value, `135`. What if I want the second or third?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603747/get-the-indices-of-n-highest-values-in-an-ndarray

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can [flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the matrix and then sort it:

```
>>> k = np.array([[ 35,  48,  63],
...        [ 60,  77,  96],
...        [ 91, 112, 135]])
>>> flat=k.flatten()
>>> flat.sort()
>>> flat
array([ 35,  48,  60,  63,  77,  91,  96, 112, 135])
>>> flat[-2]
112
>>> flat[-3]
96
```

Comment: `np.partition` may be faster - it does a partial sort, just enough to divide the array into 2 parts.

Comment: This method might be better if he wants to grab multiple elements though, say the 2nd, 3rd largest, etc... since they will all be available with no further operations other than indexing.

Comment: Is there an efficient way in `numpy` to do this without resorting the array?

Comment: @AaronLelevier sure, use `np.sort` which returns a sorted array instead of the array method, which flattens it in place: `sorted_flat = np.sort(flat)`

Answer (score 66):

As [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181350/quickest-way-to-find-nth-largest-value-in-a-numpy-matrix/43171216#comment54170091_33181395), `np.partition` should be faster (at most O(n) running time):

```
np.partition(k.flatten(), -2)[-2]
```

should return the 2nd largest element. (`partition` guarantees that the numbered element is in position, all elements before are smaller, and all behind are bigger).

Comment: > `should return the 2nd largest element` — is it true? From [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html): `The ordering of the elements in the two partitions is undefined.`

Comment: @diraria: exactly. The only position that is fixed is the 2nd position. The partitions to the left and right are always smaller and bigger, but unordered.

Comment: This solution implies that the numbers are unique. If there are duplicates, then it will not return the desired second largest number (depends on your needs).

Comment: @laorient: true, but even removing duplicates would get you up to `O(n)` running time, right ?

Answer (score 7):

Using the 'unique' function is a very clean way to do it, but likely not the fastest:

```
k = array([[ 35,  48,  63],
           [ 60,  77,  96],
           [ 91, 112, 135]])
i = numpy.unique(k)[-2]
```

for the second largest

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a=a.reshape((a.shape[0])*(a.shape[1]))  # n is the nth largest taken by us
print(a[np.argsort()[-n]])
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Your answer might be more useful if you explain your thinking.

Comment: Please check `arsort` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this when repeating elements are presented in the array at hand.
If we have something like

```
a = np.array([[1,1],[3,4]])
```

then the second largest element will be 3, not 1.

Alternatively, one could use the following snippet:

```
second_largest = sorted(list(set(a.flatten().tolist())))[-2]
```

First, flatten matrix, then only leave unique elements, then back to the mutable list, sort it and take the second element. This should return the second largest element from the end even if there are repeating elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [[ 35,  48,  63],
        [ 60,  77,  96],
        [ 91, 112, 135]]

highs = [max(lst) for lst in nums]
highs[nth]
```

Comment: Please add some info on how did you achieve this. Not just the code.

Comment: 1. for loop returns nested lists
2. max() function returns high number from nested list and appends inside highs
3. and highs[nth] - returns high number depended with index

Comment: this gives the largest value in the second row no? But the question is asking for the second largest value in the total matrix.