# Finding list of highest elements in 2D array: Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, search, optimization

I have a 2D aray of size(640X480) like this :

```
[[1.2 , 9.5 , 4.8 , 1.7],
 [5.5 , 8.1 , 7.6 , 7.1],
 [1.4 , 6.9 , 7.8 , 2.2]]     (this is a sample of a 4X3 array)
```

I have to find the top 100(or N) highest values in the array, in the FASTEST way possible; so I need the most optimised code which takes least processing time.

Since it is a giant array, it is fine if i only checked every 2nd element or every 3rd or 4th element.

The output of the algorithm should be a list of tuple, each tuple being the 2D index of the high-value element.

For example the index for 9.5 would be (0,1)

I have found a solution but it is too slow:

```
indexes=[]
for i in range(100):
    highest=-1
    highindex=0.1
    for indi,i in enumerate(array):
        for indj,j in enumerate(i):
            if j>highest and not((indi,indj) in indexes):
                highest= j
                highindex=(indi,indj)
    indexes.append(highindex)
```

Comment: I have found a way to do this but it takes too much time, what is the optimum way to do it?

Comment: Please share the *too much time taking* code.

Comment: Okay I have shared the time taking algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the indices of N highest values in an ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603747/get-the-indices-of-n-highest-values-in-an-ndarray)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

[`numpy.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html#numpy.argpartition), [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) and [`numpy.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) routines:

Test ndarray `arr` is a shuffled array with values `0` to `99` of shape `(11, 9)`.
Let's say we want to find the list of 2d indices of top 7 largest values:

```
In [1018]: arr
Out[1018]: 
array([[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98],
       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
       [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]])

In [1019]: top_N = 7

In [1020]: idx = np.argpartition(arr, arr.size - top_N, axis=None)[-top_N:]

In [1021]: result = np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(idx, arr.shape))

In [1022]: result
Out[1022]: 
array([[7, 2],
       [7, 3],
       [7, 4],
       [7, 5],
       [7, 7],
       [7, 8],
       [7, 6]])
```

Comment: I get an error:

ValueError: kth(=-98) out of bounds (1)

Comment: What do you get for `arr.size - top_N`?

Comment: @VikhyatAgarwal, what's your current code? Note, that when doing such partitioning `top_N` should not be larger than the number of columns of the initial array

Comment: top_N = 100         ;                              
idx = np.argpartition(arr, arr.size - top_N, axis=None)[-top_N:]                     ;           
result = np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(idx, arr.shape))                 ;

Comment: what's your current `arr.shape` and `arr.ndim`?

Comment: arr.shape just returns ()

Comment: ndim is 0... maybe these errors are because I am pasting the array using pyperclip module..???

Comment: @VikhyatAgarwal, that is the answer: you are testing an uninitialized or an empty array. Check your array initialization/filling code

Comment: Yes that is true . Thanks for the help... I'll work on that

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,this was much faster than my method; this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I thought of, hopefully it's fast enough for your needs.

```
num_list = [
    [1.2, 9.5, 4.8, 1.7],
    [5.5, 8.1, 7.6, 7.1],
    [5.5, 9.6, 7.6, 7.1],
    [5.5, 8.1, 4.5, 7.1],
    [1.4, 6.9, 7.8, 12.2]
]

needed_highest = 5 # This is where your 100 would go
highest = [-1] * needed_highest
result = [-1] * needed_highest

for y in range(0, len(num_list)):
    for x in range(0, len(num_list[y])):
        num = num_list[y][x]
        min_index = highest.index(min(highest))
        min_value = highest[min_index]
        if min_value < num:
            highest[min_index] = num
            result[min_index] = (x, y)
print(result)
```

The result isn't sorted in any manner, but it shouldn't be to hard to implement that if it's needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No worries, hope it helped